# is there possible to show local notification package to show api new get data - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, local

Is there any possibility to do, from API get data to show notification in flutter using Flutter_Local_Notifications.

If this is possible please let me share a tutorial or some code to get an Idea.

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Edit your AndroidManifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Add this inside the application section

```
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
```

Continue with the following [link.](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/local-push-notification-in-flutter-763605b84985)

Comment: Can you help me to get notification from API - this is for button to notifications